# Android Chrome HTML5 playhead glitches every minute or so?

Tags: html5

Whenever I play either an embedded HTML5 video or just watch it from the direct link on my Android device, the video plays for about 1 minute then stops as if it's trying to buffer. I tap the screen to bring up the GUI (so I can drag the playhead back a little) but nothing happens for a few seconds. Then it comes up but all the buffered video has disappeared and the time that the playhead is at will be about a few seconds ahead in time from when you pressed the play button initially. Sometimes it flicks between seconds. I then have to guess how far through my video I am and reposition the playhead for it to continue playing until I have to do it again. It's extremely tedious and annoying. Another thing is that when the video stops and the playhead glitches, sometimes the sound will keep playing as if the video had just been buffering but the video stays frozen.

Example: I start playing from 0:00 and watch til about 1:30 (I don't see that I am at 1:30). The video freezes and I look at the playhead which flickers between 0:05 and 0:06. I reposition the play head at about where I think I got up to and the video plays as normal for about another minute until it happens again.

I am running Cyanogen 12S on a OnePlus One.
I'm using the latest Chrome Beta app for Android L.